Why is my Swiper component not working in Angular17? The images won't load, just the first, the index changes, but the images don't, and bugs
product.carousel.component.html
   <swiper-container loop="true" navigation="true">
      @for (image of images; track $index) {
      <swiper-slide>
        <img class="item" src="{{ image.imageUrl }}" alt=""
      /></swiper-slide>
      }
    </swiper-container>

product.carousel.component.ts

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-product-carousel',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [CommonModule],
      providers: [],
      templateUrl: './product-carousel.component.html',
      styleUrl: './product-carousel.component.scss',
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    })

main.ts:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

register();

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err)
);

I'm trying to make a carousel with images of product, but when I try to swipe, the image flicks and don't change, just the index

Already found a solution!
This worked great to me:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3599#issuecomment-953430779
